# How to implement Restful design to request webpage stored for magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I have a question concerning how to implement restful design to request webpage stored in magnolia JCR.

For example,

I have a list page called itemList [www.example.com/itemList], which contains a list of item.

And i have a item page [www.example.com/itemList/item/1], which is a child page of itemList (which can be seen in the PAGES app).

If i want to get item with ID no.1, just like other restful design, just use URL [www.example.com/itemList/item/1], and it will return whole page of item with item no.1 data (which i need to store the ID and pass it to the JAVA custom module in template script to get the data)

But here is the problem,

as i study in the magnolia documentation, like

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/How+to+create+a+custom+Java-based+REST+endpoint

it just tell about create rest endpoint and get the JSON data back as for manuplation.

And i got stuck at how to achieve my goal, may i have some suggestions?

Thanks a lot for any help. ORZ

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Magnolia you don't need to create a custom endpoint for that, you can use the pre-defined ones which are sufficient to achieve what you want. Have a look  at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/REST+API

Let me know if that covers what you need or any other extra questions that should you have.

Hope that helps,

Cheers,